# arithmetic expression Math.random in java

Tags: java

the purpose of this program is to let the user try to guess a number up to 20 randomly chosen by the computer. The user inputs their guess. The computer then tells the user if their guess is too high or too low. The user keeps inputting their guess until theu guess correctly. Then they are told how many guesses it took them. The problem is that I am not understanding whether the arithmetic expression in the program generates random numbers from 1 to 20 because when I am inputting numbers from 1 to 20, the pop-up says 'number is too big'.

```
package pkTopic6Exercise13;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.Font;
public class Topic6Exercise13 
{
private GuessingGame MyGuessingGame = new GuessingGame();
private Topic6Exercise13()
{//constructor      
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Topic6Exercise13 myTopic6Exercise13 = new Topic6Exercise13();
    myTopic6Exercise13.go();
}
private void go()
{
    T6Ex13GUIin myT6Ex13GUIin = new T6Ex13GUIin();
}
private class GuessingGame
{
    private int NumToGuess=0;
    private int Guess=0;
    private int NumGuesses=0;
    private GuessingGame()
    {//constructor          
    }
    private void GenerateNum()
    {
        NumToGuess = 1+(int)(20*Math.random());
    }
    private String CheckNum()
    {
        NumGuesses = NumGuesses + 1;
        if (Guess > NumToGuess)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Guess + " is too BIG!");
            return "NotGuessed";
        }
        else if (Guess < NumToGuess)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Guess + " is too SMALL!");
            return "NotGuessed";
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Well done! " + Guess +" is correct, it took " + NumGuesses + " goes.");
            return "Guessed";
        }
    }
}
private class T6Ex13GUIin extends JFrame
{
    private JLabel lblGuess;
    private JTextField txfGuess;
    private JButton btnPickNumber;
    private JButton btnQuit;

    private T6Ex13GUIin()
    {//constructor
        Font fontDialog = new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD,24);
        this.setSize(1000,500);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLocation(100,0);
        this.setTitle("Guessing Game");
        this.setLayout(null);
        lblGuess = new JLabel("Type Guess:");
        lblGuess.setFont(fontDialog);
        lblGuess.setBounds(100,200,200,50);
        lblGuess.setVisible(false);
        this.add(lblGuess);
        txfGuess = new JTextField("");
        txfGuess.setBounds(300,200,100,50);
        txfGuess.setFont(fontDialog);
        txfGuess.setVisible(false);
        ReturnListener MyReturnListener = new ReturnListener();
        txfGuess.addKeyListener(MyReturnListener);
        this.add(txfGuess);
        ClickListener MyClickListener = new ClickListener();
        btnPickNumber = new JButton("Pick Number");
        btnPickNumber.setBounds(100,100,750,50);
        btnPickNumber.setFont(fontDialog);
        btnPickNumber.addActionListener(MyClickListener);
        this.add(btnPickNumber);
        btnQuit = new JButton("Quit");
        btnQuit.setBounds(750,300,100,50);
        btnQuit.setFont(fontDialog);
        btnQuit.addActionListener(MyClickListener);
        this.add(btnQuit);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
    private class ClickListener implements ActionListener
    {
        private ClickListener()
        {//constructor              
        }
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {               
            if (e.getSource() == btnPickNumber)
            {
                MyGuessingGame.GenerateNum();
                MyGuessingGame.NumGuesses=0;
                btnPickNumber.setVisible(false);
                lblGuess.setVisible(true);
                txfGuess.setVisible(true);
                txfGuess.setText("");
            }
            if (e.getSource() == btnQuit)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
    private class ReturnListener implements KeyListener
    {
        private ReturnListener()
        {//constructor
        }
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
        }
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
        }
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getKeyChar() == '\n')
            {
                MyGuessingGame.Guess = 
                Integer.parseInt(txfGuess.getText());
                if (MyGuessingGame.CheckNum().equals("Guessed"))
                {
                    lblGuess.setVisible(false);
                    txfGuess.setVisible(false);
                    btnPickNumber.setVisible(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    txfGuess.setText("");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Your call to [Math.random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random%28%29) is perfectly okay. Error must be somewhere else.

Comment: Are you sure that the `generateNum()` method is being called?

Comment: @SamIam That won't make a difference, as `Math.random()` returns a `double` anyways and `20` will be automatically promoted

Comment: @SamIam: wouldn't matter, his code correctly generates the numbers as he wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried any testing?  Like, debugging and seeing what value is getting set for NumToGuess?  Or perhaps simply displaying the value being set?  Then if you know what the random number is, you can test out your logic.

Based on your core logic, I ran this simple code below and didn't experience any problems.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int NumToGuess = 1+(int)(20*Math.random());
    int myGuess    = Integer.parseInt("10"); 
    System.out.println("Value is: " + NumToGuess);
    System.out.println("My Guess: " + myGuess);

    if (myGuess > NumToGuess) {
        System.out.println("Too Big");
    }
    else if (myGuess < NumToGuess) {
        System.out.println("Too Small");
    }

}
```

Comment: yes i did run and test several times, but either am getting 'too small' or 'too big' though am inputting numbers between 1 and 20

Comment: Isn't that the point of your program?

-Generate a random number between 1 and 20.  
-User inputs a guess.  
-User input is compared against generated number.  
-Output is generated identifying if user input was larger, smaller, or equal to the generated number.

Comment: yes exactly but the generated randoms are supposed to be between 1 and 20 as per the expression in the program

Comment: So, are you getting randomly generated values that are less than 1 or greater than 20 ?

Comment: na it say too small or too big

Comment: @kevin: That doesn't answer the question though. Are you *debugging* the code with breakpoints and actually **watching** what's happening? This would be a simple way to at least get a clue of what the issue is.

Comment: @kevin:  Are you saying that the value of NumToGuess is getting set to "too small" or "too big" ? 

That shouldn't be possible.  Your NumToGuess variable is an int...

Comment: sorry @Chiefwarpaint it working fine - i made a mistake

Comment: No problem @kevin.  Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score -1):

`Math.rand()` generates a random number between 0 and 1 exclusive. So by multiplying by 20 you get a value between 0 and 20 exclusive. By rounding down with the `(int)` cast it becomes between 0-19 inclusive and by adding one it becomes between 1-20 inclusive. So yes, your number is being generated correctly. However, you do add 1 again at the beginning of the `checkNum()` method so that could be a problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually, the chances of getting 20 from `Math.random() * 20` should be exactly 0, because `Math.random()` returns a `double` between 0 inclusive and 1 *exclusive*.

Comment: Read it again, my bad.

Comment: BTW - check your last statement; I don't think op is incrementing the guess.